# MS Access - Listbox bound to query is empty except when all fields are filled

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a simple listbox in a form. I have a button that runs a query and requeries the listbox. When the query results have all the fields filled in a row, the listbox works as expected. The problem is when there are any blank fields for the results, they don't appear in the listbox.

Do I need replace the null fields in the query with some character like " " so that it properly displays?

Comment: Why are fields blank? What table is source for listbox? What do you mean by 'runs a query' - what is this query?

Comment: The query it is reading from (FormQuery) isn't designed to have each field completely filled. So a row might only have some of the cells filled.

The source query (FormQuery) has 20 columns and a dynamic number of rows.

The button has a macro assigned which Requeries the list. FormQuery is the row source for the listbox.

Comment: Somehow now it's working for me. I cleared the default column widths and just added 1" and now it works perfectly.